# No Dynamic Text will correctly show, why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, text

I am learning rudementary flash, and have a book in hand; but am beginning to wonder if there is something wrong with the program or my computer. The following should be simple but only gives me nothing in the dynamic text box or just pieces of letters.

Frame 1

```
var amount:Number = 1;
```

Frame 2

```
howmuch.text = String (amount);
```

and....nothing ever shows....like ever. I've used this in a simple loop according to the actionscript 3.0 lesson including an `amount++` function to make a simple counter.

I'm trying to get each concept and build on it, but have been here at lesson one for days.

using Adobe Flash CC on an iMac I bought here in 2013 running Mountain Lion.
Help please.

Comment: Try embedding the font. And - not 100% since I never used frame scripting, but - it might be that var amount is empty since is it other frame. Try trace(amount) to check this.

Comment: have you tried starting with just one frame?

Answer (score 0):

Because your text field is a dynamic one you may need to embed the font. Also check if the text color is not the same as the color of the background.